# Maxima, minima, and the mvt application

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I have a quiz on "Maxima, minima, and the mean value theorem" and I don't even know which topic to apply to this question:

If $f''(x) \ge  -1$, $x$ belongs to $(-15, 15)$, and $f'(1)=3$, find the interval over which $x$ is definitely increasing.

Please help :( this is making me so sad.

Comment: Suppose $x \ge y$, the you have $f'(x)-f'(y) = f''(\xi)(x-y)$ for some $\xi \in [y,x]$.

Comment: How to I use that? The notation looks foreign. I'm working from Calculus by James Stewart.

Comment: What notation are you referring to? All of my notation appears in the question.

Comment: Is that the only formula I use to find the interval? The only given values that I can sub in are : f'(x)=f'(1)=3 and x=1, but that leaves me with three unknowns in the equation.

Comment: I haven't done maths in five years so forgive me for asking ridiculous questions. It looks pretty straightforward but I just can't seem to grasp what I'm supposed to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is non decreasing **iff** $f'(x) \ge 0$.

Let $g(x) = f'(x)$ to keep the problem tick free inasmuch as possible.

We are given that $g'(x) \ge -1$, $g(1) = 3$.

By drawing a picture, we can surmise that for $x \ge 1$, the worst case
is when $g'(x) = -1$ and so $g(x) \ge 0$ as long as $x \ge 4$. For $x < 1$, we can imagine a function for which $g(x) <0$, but $g$ grows
quickly enough so that $g(1) = 3$. Hence our guess is that we can
only guarantee $g(x) \ge 0$ for $x \in [1,4]$.

To validate the guess, note that for $x >1$ the mean value theorem
shows that there is some $\xi \in [1,x]$ such that
${g(x)-3 \over x-1 } = g'(\xi) \ge -1$ from which we see that
if $x \ge 4$ then $ g(x) \ge 0$.
Furthermore, by considering $g(x) = 4 -x$ we see that $4$ is the
best upper limit.

For $x<1$, consider the collection of functions
$g_n(t) = 3-e^{-n(t-1)}$ and note that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = -\infty$ and $g'(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. hence we see that $0$ is
the best lower limit.